# Google Drive API upload file with custom property, properties missing from response

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to save a google drive file with custom properties, but its not working and due to the very poor documentation of the Google API, i am struggeling with this. Here is my code so far:

```
$g = new FileCtrl();
$fileMeta = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$fileMeta->name = $file['name'];
$fileMeta->parents = [$g->googleDriveFolderId];
$fileMeta->appProperties = (object)['lead_id'=>$file['lid'], 'sales_package_id'=>$file['pid'], 'user_id'=>$user->uid];
//$fileMeta->size = $file['size'];

$fileData = array(
              'data' => $fileContent,
              'mimeType' => $file['media_type'],
              'uploadType' => $file['multipart'],
            );

 //create file in google drive
$res = $g->client->files->create($fileMeta, $fileData);
```

It is not returning an error and the event is saved, but without the custom properties!?

Comment: And your code throws an error?   does nothing?  Welcome to stack you need to give us an idea what your problem is with the code you have posted.

Comment: It is not returning an error and the event is saved, but without the custom properties!?

Comment: Where are you checking that the custom proprieties are not inserted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the properties in the returned file resource.

The reason they aren't there is that Drive only returns a small number of the file properties (name, mime type, id). If you want to see the full file resource you need to include `fields=*` in the request. So a correct request would look something like

`POST https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*`

I don't know the PHP library, so you'll need to figure that bit out. It will be something like

`'fields' => '*',`

Comment: thanks, this worked fine. your guess was correct: 'fields' => '*',

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this.

Request:

```
{
  "name": "Linda Test",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
  "appProperties": {
    "TestingId": "1"
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1mhP2EW4Kbl81F5AuJ4zJ2IPoeI56i_Vd5K-dfGJRj6Y",
 "name": "Linda Test",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
}
```

Do a file.get to check the file metadata.

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1mhP2EW4Kbl81F5AuJ4zJ2IPoeI56i_Vd5K-dfGJRj6Y",
 "name": "Linda Test",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "parents": [
  "0AJpJkOVaKccEUk9PVA"
 ],
 "appProperties": {
  "TestingId": "1"
 },
  ...
}
```

I suggest you check your uploaded file using the [File.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) method after its returned to be sure that it was added.   To my knowledge there is now way to see these added fields via the Google drive website interface.   If after ruining a file.get you still find that it wasn't uploaded i suggest you log this as a bug with the [Google APIs PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) library team.  This works with raw rest requests it could be an issue with the library.